# Ability to store selections

Tags: selection-tools

Is there something similar to vertex groups for faces and edges? I find vertex groups incredibly useful for remembering custom selections I've made.

What I want to do is select faces or edges, and be able to reselect them later as easy as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think anything like this exists currently (there is [a proposal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Face/Edge_groups_proposal)), but in the meantime it's probably possible to implement something with python.

Comment: Yeah I would expect you would be able to easily retrieve selected components in some array, store it then reselect it. I'll have a look around.

Comment: Why wouldn't vertex groups work... since faces and edges are made up over vertices...

Comment: @GiantCowFilms can you add faces and edges to vertex groups? If not then you need to select them as vertices which means if i need to manipulate faces then selecting as vertices would be useless.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Here's an example. You can't possibly select just [these edges](http://pasteall.org/pic/73642) in vertex mode. Here's [what happens](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/73644) if you try (the connecting edges and face are now also selected).

Comment: @gandalf3 Oops, I forgot about those selections... sorry!

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Nothing to be sorry about (I'm not angry..). :)

Comment: It's not possible to implement it well in Python, as custom layer data propagates on actions like extrusion. So if you stored the selection state of edges or faces as a property of these elements, it would be copied over to the new elements when you extrude etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this feature will most likely never make it into the official release of blender.

As CoDEmanX said,

> It's not possible to implement it well in Python, as custom layer data propagates on actions like extrusion. So if you stored the selection state of edges or faces as a property of these elements, it would be copied over to the new elements when you extrude etc.

Also it is important to notice that there are some selection difficulties that would come into play. in spite of all that, there is [**a proposal**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Face/Edge_groups_proposal) for such a feature, and it may become possible in the future.