# Why are extra faces deselected when deselecting vertex groups?

Tags: vertex-groups

1. Subdivide a cube and assign 4 faces to a vertex group.
2. Assign the whole cube to another vertex group.
3. Select the whole cube with a click on vertex group 2.
4. Try to deselect the 4 faces with a click on vertex group 1,
   but a lot more faces are deselected.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13856/599

Answer (score 2):

This is because they are *vertex* groups, not face groups.

Deselecting a vertex group will deselect all the vertices in that group, which will also deselect any faces which those vertices where a part of.

Think of it this way: For a face to be selected, all the vertices which make up that face must also be selected. So by deselecting a single vertex in the subdivided cube example, you actually deselect four faces:

[image]

If you deselect the vertices in your group manually, you'll get the same result as clicking the deselect button on the group.

What you want are *Face groups*, however unfortunately there is no support for these yet. There is [a proposal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Face/Edge_groups_proposal) though.

Comment: you can use materials as face groups however it is a bit limited compared to real face group support.

Comment: @MarcClintDion That's quite clever, I hadn't even considered that.. Nice idea! Still, true face and edge groups would be nice.